# How to pass an object to a component in a for loop in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass an object to a component in an angular template:

```
<note-setting
  *ngFor="let setting of settings"
  [settingData]="setting"
></note-setting>
```

how do I do this correctly? the setting that is declared in the `*ngFor` should be passed in the `[settingData]` field to the `note-setting` component.

I don't understand why this is so difficult to figure out, I've been using react for 3 years and it's so much simpler, I just do:

```
settings.map(setting => <NoteSetting settingData={setting} />)
```

Also, every angular tutorial I've seen only shows how to pass primitive types like ints and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `settingData` as an `@Input` property in the `note-setting` component. You can check the bound value in `ngOnInit`.

```
export class NoteSettingComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() settingData: SettingData; // use the appropriate type here

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.settingData);
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2t8rg) for a demo.

Comment: i already did that, that's not my question. My question is about the right way to structure the code I showed at the top - is the syntax right?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the syntax in your code snippet. If you declared the `@Input` property, it probably already works. Does it?

Comment: no it's showing me undefined for the settingData, I'm comparing the stackblitz to my code now

Comment: What about `settings` in the parent component? Is that an array of objects?

Comment: strangely, in the `note-setting` component's html template, the settingData renders correctly, but in the constructor of the component ts file, it keeps saying undefined. This is what my constructor looks like: `constructor() { console.log('data', this.settingData); }` which is why I thought it wasn't working

Comment: It's because the binding is not done yet in the constructor. Try showing the value in `ngOnInit` instead.